# How can I improve this sentence stylistically

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

> My mother burst into tears about how I was changing. That was, for I lately indeed had begun to show some rebel attitude.

Is the latter sentence understandable, clean and grammatically okay?

I am especially unsure about the 'That was, for I' construction, as I am a non-native speaker.

Comment: "That was understandable"

Comment: Grammatically okay. Stylistically awful. Do note that questions of the form "is this sentence grammatically okay" are expressly off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask for a better explanation for what makes it stylistically awful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cater to the change in the question:

> My mother burst into tears about how I was changing. **That was**, for I lately indeed had begun to show some rebel attitude.

In my opinion, the bad style is due to the phrase "That was" - it provides no benefit, because from the previous sentence it is already known that you are providing a reason for the mother's crying. Removing it will work better, along with making the edit proposed by Jason:

> My mother burst into tears about how I was changing, for lately I had indeed begun to show some rebel attitude.

The word "indeed" is also unnecessary in my opinion, as there is no reason to doubt the sentence, as it is first person.

> My mother burst into tears about how I was changing, for lately I had begun to show some rebel attitude.

or

> My mother burst into tears about how I was changing, for **I had lately** begun to show some rebel attitude.

Comment: Thank you very much. As a final question: Is there any difference in the comprehension of the last two examples, or is it mereley a difference in syntax?

Comment: "some rebel attitude" doesn't sound like native AmEnglish. Alternatives could be "show a rebel attitude" (eh), "show a rebellious attitude" or "begun to rebel against her strictures."

Comment: The final two are exactly the same in terms of comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "that was" can be implied to mean "that was happening" or "that happened" - it is perfectly fine (grammatically) in this context.

However, I would change this part:

> burst into tears **about** how I was changing

The word "about" doesn't seem right. I would prefer "because of" or "over"

> My mother burst into tears **because of** how I was changing.

or

> My mother burst into tears **over** how I was changing.

Answer (score 0):

> My mother burst into tears about how I was changing. That was, **for lately I had indeed** begun to show some rebel attitude.

Without spoiling any stylistic preferences you may have, I suggest the above edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would much appreciate to learn about the differences in the perception of readers, regarding the two expressions.

Comment: I would also love to learn why this was downvoted